# Make any word in label text as button programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, button, label

I have been searching for ways to do the following

Label: "Your favorite color [Blue] / [Red]"

- where Blue and Red are buttons
- app has 2 type of fields picked from database as random question
  a) text
  b) buttons on text

So, I get "Your favorite color Blue / Red" - type text & (Blue, Red) type button.

I would like to render buttons at the exact place where Blue & Red appears on label. The font size is going to be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get label width according to text

```
CGSize labelSize = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.font 
                            constrainedToSize:myLabel.frame.size 
                                lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

and then calculate single char width

```
CGFloat labelSingleCharWidth = labelSize.width/"numberOfCharInLabelString";
```

and after this get range

```
 NSRange range = [myLabel.text rangeOfString:@"Blue"];
```

it will return location and length of "Blue". according to this make frame of your button like this

```
myButton.frame=CGRectMake(range.location*labelSingleCharWidth , 0 , range.length*labelSingleCharWidth , labelSize.heigth );
```

it helps You.